# Use .Net Standard library in .Net Framework 4.7 application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0, asp-net-mvc-1

I have a set of class libraries which are developed using .Net Standard 2.0. One of these class libraries implements the `IAuthorizationFilter` interface which is resides in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters` namespace.

```
public class AuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public AuthorizationFilter() {}

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {/*Code cropped for the case of simplicity*/}
}
```

The other class library's main responsibility is to register the Dependency Injection configuration.

```
   public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection MyCustomConfigure(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //...Code cropped for the case of simplicity
            services.AddMvc(config => { config.Filters.Add(typeof(AuthorizationFilter)); });
            return services;
        }
}
```

Beside these .Net Standard class libraries, I have a web application project developed using `ASP.Net MVC`(.Net Framework 4.7)

I have two main problem here:

1. I need to add my `FilterAttribute` class, to `ASP.Net MVC's` filter list, which throws an exception saying:

> The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following
>   filter interfaces: System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter, System.Web.Mvc.IResultFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter,
>   System.Web.Mvc.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter.

I registered the filter in this way in my ASP.Net MVC application:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        //...Code cropped for the case of simplicity
        filters.Add(typeof(AuthorizationFilter));
    }
}
```

apparently I do not want to add reference to `System.Web` in my .Net Standard class libraries, on the other hand, I do not know how to resolve this problem!

2. The second problem, is the place where I can call my `services.MyCustomConfigure()` method. In .Net Core applications I called this method inside `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class,but I do not know how to call this in `ASP.Net MVC`!

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
       //...Code cropped for the case of simplicity
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.MyCustomConfigure()
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET (WebForms, MVC, WebAPI) and ASP.NET Core are different frameworks and while they share similar concepts (like filter attributes), they are different and you cannot use components written for ASP.NET Core using its APIs (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.*`) for classic ASP.NET.

This means that you will need to have different implementations for ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: thank you. this means that even I can not get access to the registered types(registered by IServiceProvider) in ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: Exactly, they inherent from classes only known to ASP.NET Core